# Bootstrap4 How to adjust the bootstrap class of a grid element but only if the grid breaks down?

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

Is it somehow possible to adjust the bootstrap class of a grid element from `col-md-9` to `col-md-12` but only if the grid breaks (e.g. because of resizing the browser window).

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/kp41m0xq/

```html
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <!-- Something, graph or so -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <!-- Something, graph or so -->
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

This will look like e.g. the following when the window is big enough:

[image]

but very bad if the window is small:

[image]

How it should look like with a small window:

[image]

Is it possible to get the effect that the class is `col-md-9` (first picture) if the window is big enough and `col-md-12` (third picture) it the window is small? It would be great if this was possible with bootstrap itself. Otherwise I could use jquery as well.

Comment: use the small classes coll-sm-* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a combination of classes for smaller screens

```
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <!-- Something, graph or so -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9">
    <!-- Something, graph or so -->
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

or use general classes

```
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <!-- Something, graph or so -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-9">
    <!-- Something, graph or so -->
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I think, I need to investigate my setup... In the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5ayf9mLk/ your solution works as expected...

Comment: I think you need to read Bootstrap documentation before trying it, FranzHuber23 .

Comment: The reason was a `style="min-width: 330px; max-width: 330px;"` element on the same level as the `col-` stuff which caused the problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 'col-sm-12' class along with 'col-md-9' class as follows

```
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <!-- Something, graph or so -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12">
    <!-- Something, graph or so -->
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```